# How to configure ASP.NET membership after removing SQL Express 2008 and installing SQL 2008 R2 Enterprise

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, asp.net-membership

As the title says, I used to have SQL Express 2008 on my machine. After creating a new Web application, Visual Studio would automatically create the **aspnetdb.mdf** database and add a connection string to the Web.config file.

Since installing the full version I've found, to my surprise, that it's not possible to reference a local .mdf database any more. Firstly, is that true?

With that in mind, I used aspnet_regsql.exe to create an **aspnetdb.dbo** database on my local server. I then used the 'Server Explorer', in VisualStudio, to attach that database to the 'Data Connections'.

The problem is, every time I create a new web application, it sticks a local SQLExpress connection string into the project template.

Is there something else I have to do to rectify this?

Thanks